# How to write directly in the SEARCH boxes of websites with R

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I am looking for a way to do web scraping on a web page after typing in its search box. Let me explain better with an example: I am looking for an R function that writes the word "notebook" directly on the amazon home page so that I can subsequently do web scraping of that generated page.
Any help?
Any suggestions?
Maybe I could do it in Python?
Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In python you have several modules designed for web scraping, i let you a list with the most common ones.

- [Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)
- [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html#introduction)
- [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
- [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Just scrape the webpage from

```
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=whatever you want to search
```

Any sort of website will give you a url with a query when you search. just scrape from that url.